# how to provide a special SSO filter that is able to pass the ticket to the Alfresco Repository?

Tags: java, filter, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to develop a Java class that implements the Java Servlet API interface "Filter" and register it in the web.xml of Share. In that class, the doFilter method needs to take care of passing a ticket from the request URI to the backend Repository to verify / validate. Can any one give me the code?

Comment: Did you try following the [Alfresco Documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fauth-alfrescoexternal-sso.html) on the topic?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't implement this. Please provide me the Class.

Comment: If you want the solution on a plate, give Alfresco Support or Alfresco Consulting a call, they'll be happy to do all the work for you. If not, please tell us what you tried, and where you got stuck